# Casting a string as decimal in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, string-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string to a decimal using this command:

```
SELECT cast(minimum_ticket_price AS DECIMAL(6,2) 
FROM all_event_details 
WHERE minimum_ticket_price ~ E'^\\d+$';
```

But this doesn't actually update anything in my database. It just displays the selected column in my terminal. Do I need to combine the select with an update? I've tried that but I must have the syntax wrong as I'm not able to get the conversion saved in the database.

Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE all_event_details 
   SET minimum_ticket_price = cast(minimum_ticket_price AS DECIMAL(6,2)) 
WHERE ( minimum_ticket_price <> '') IS TRUE;;
```

Comment: You need to change the column's data type. You can't update with an "incorrect" value. But  you cannot change the data type as long as there is a single value that is **not** a decimal. And. `minimum_ticket_price <> ''` is enough, no need for the `is true`

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a data type which minimum_ticket_price column's data can support  is possible otherwise it will give an error.
for example if minimum_ticket_price column data type is varchar then your code must work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing? 
First add new column, decimal(but I'm goint to suggest to use the basics data type such real or double precision, are most efficient)

```
 ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN minimum_ticket_priceR  real ;
```

than

```
 UPDATE all_event_details 
    SET minimum_ticket_priceR = to_number(coalesce(minimum_ticket_price,"0"),"999999D99") --for each row
```

than I'm going to suggest to drop the colum minimum_ticket_price and rename the other column (ever with ALTER TABLE):
What you did is not to understand, if minimum_ticket_price is string, you cannot set a number... and if is a number has no meaning to set it as string